# Data insert in sqlit table in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, insert

I have sqlit data base i want to insert data in data base problem is that when i insert data it shows following error in insert query.

```
- (void) addCoffee {
    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into library(userID,contentAddedDateTime,contentType,contentTitle,contentSource,contentDescription,categoryTitle,subCategoryTitle,organizationCode,userName) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [userID UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [contentAddedDateTime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [contentType UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [contentTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [contentSource UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 8, [contentDescription UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 9, [categoryTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [subCategoryTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 11, [organizationCode UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        coffeeID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

Error which shows is:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'out of memory''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your database before querying it.

Open you database using [sqlite3_open()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).

Have this line before `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

```
if (sqlite3_open([databaseFilePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Also make use of `sqlite3_finalize(statement);` and `sqlite3_close(database);` once you done inserting data.